# how to call on the input in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, input, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I would like to give a class to each input in this scenario but I don't know how to.

**JS:**

```
  document.getElementsByClassName("parent")[0].addEventListener("click",function(){ document.getElementsByClassName("maco")[0].innerHTML="<form><wrap>Name: <input></wrap><wrap>Date Range from <input> to <input></wrap><wrap>Reason:<input></wrap><wrap>Name of Parent:<input></wrap><wrap><button>Enter<button></wrap></form>";
     document.getElementsByClassName("parent")[0].getElementsByTagName("form")[0].classList.add("pl");
     document.getElementsByClassName("parent")[0].getElementsByTagName("form")[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].classList.add("first");
     document.getElementsByClassName("parent")[0].getElementsByTagName("form")[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[1].classList.add("second");
     document.getElementsByClassName("parent")[0].getElementsByTagName("form")[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[2].classList.add("third");
     document.getElementsByClassName("parent")[0].getElementsByTagName("form")[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[3].classList.add("fourth");
     document.getElementsByClassName("parent")[0].getElementsByTagName("form")[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[4].classList.add("fifth"); });
```

i did the above but the browser kept saying Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined

Is there a way to give each input in the quote in innerHTML="..." a class?

Comment: getElementsByClassName is a function of Document object, not Element objects, so you could use querySelector or querySelectorAll or you could use the elements property of HTMLFormElement objects. However if you could explain better the scenario (it is quite difficult to follow in the code you posted) maybe I can come out with a better fitting solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't post your HTML structure it's hard to be sure this will work, but assuimg your tree is like this:

```
<div class="parent">
   <form>
      <input>
      <input>
      <input>
   </form>
</div>
```

Here's how I would do this.

```js
const numericalWords = [
  "first",
  "second",
  "third"
]


document.querySelectorAll('.parent form input').forEach((input, i) => {
  input.classList.add(numericalWords[i])
 })
```

```css
.first {
    background: yellow;
 }
 
 .second {
    background: blue;
 }
 
.third {
    background: green;
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<form>
  <input>
  <input>
  <input>
</form>
</div>
```